# Python vowel check

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there are a few ways to remove vowels, but when I try the method below, the output I get is the string just being printed `len(string)` times.  For example:

```
s="Labido Labidi"
for i in s:
        if i.lower()=='a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':    
            s=s.replace(i,"")
            print(s)
```

The resultant output is:

```
Labido Labidi
Labido Labidi 
...and so on
```

What's going on inside the loop ?  It isn't even going through the if statement.

Comment: That's not the actual output. Please edit your post to include the correct output from your code. Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/198633)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the or statement incorrectly:

```
s="Labido Labidi"
for i in s:
    if i.lower()=='a' or i.lower()=='e' or i.lower()=='i' or i.lower()=='o' or i.lower()=='u':    
        s=s.replace(i,"")
        print(s)
```

You need to put your full evaluational statement after the or

Comment: What about 'for i.lower() in s', much shorter

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your if logic.
After the first `or` you have to repeat `i.lower() == 'e'`, etc.

Try this:

```
s="Labido Labidi"
for i in s:
        if i.lower() in 'aeiou':    
            s=s.replace(i,"")
            print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `if` condition.  *or* connects two boolean expressions; it doesn't work the same as in English.  What you need to check is

```
if i.lower()=='a' or 
   i.lower()=='e' or
   ...
```

Better yet, just make a single check on a list of vowels this way:

```
if lower() in "aeiou":
```

---

DETAILS

```
Any expression used as a Boolean value is evaluated according to whether it is "truthy" or "falsey".  Non-Boolean data types are sometimes not obvious.  In general, zero and `None` values are "falsey", and everything else is "truthy".
```

Thus, each of the single letters is "truthy", so the Python interpreter regards your `if` statement as if it says

```
if i.lower()=='a' or True or True or True or True:
```

In short, this is *always* True; your program thinks that everything is a vowel.